# how to observe an integer of a different class

Tags: c#, events, observable

I have a class called game, The game has a list of players (I do not have access to the Player class!).
Each player has an integer that represent the number of life points he has left
like so

```
class Player
{
    public int Life;
    ....
}
```

I need to alert the Game class every time a player's life is changed, The Game class look like so

```
class Game
{
    public void OnPlayerLifeChange();
    ....
}
```

I want to activate the function `OnPlayerLifeChange` whenever the `Life` member is changed, how can I do it?.
again note that I cant change the Player class and make life a property with an event.

Comment: Well tell whoever made that `Player` class to not name variables with a capital letter like a barbarian.

Answer (score 0):

The person that wrote the Player class needs to add a public method to check for any updates to the `Life` variable.  Then you just need to make use of that method.

If the person did not write such a method, then you cannot access it (that's why encapsulation is important, otherwise anyone can access something that isn't meant to be accessed)

Answer (score 0):

One common way to do this is to implement the INotifyPropertyChanged interface in the Player class, change Life from a field to a property and raise the PropertyChanged event from the setter.

```
class Player : INotofyPropertyChanged
{
    private int _life;
    public int Life
    {
        get { return _life; }
        set { _life = value; OnPropertyChanged("Life"); }
    }

    ....
}
```

Game can then subscribe to the PropertyChanged events of all players and react accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Without access to the Player class, one option would be to just check the values of the Life variable for all the players on a set interval.

You would need to keep local variables within your Game class to keep track of what the Life variables were previously set to, but whenever you noticed that one of the values of a Life variable had changed you could execute whatever code you needed to within the Game class, which would give you basically the same behavior as an event handler (although probably not as effecient).

```
class Game {    

    List<Player> playerList;
    ArrayList lifeValues;
    System.Timers.Timer lifeCheckTimer;

    Game() {
        playerList = new List<Player>();
        //add all players that have been instantiated to the above list here
        lifeValues = new ArrayList();
        //add all the player.Life values to the above list here
        //these will need to be added in the same order
        lifeCheckTimer = new System.Timers.Timer();
        lifeCheckTimer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(lifeCheckElapsed);
        //you can change the 500 (0.5 seconds) below to whatever interval you want to 
        //check for a change in players life values (in milliseconds)
        lifeCheckTimer.Interval = 500;
        lifeCheckTimer.Enabled = true;
    }

    private static void lifeCheckElapsed(object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < playerList.Count(); i ++) {
            if (((Player)playerList[i]).Life != lifeValues[i])
                OnPlayerLifeChange();
            lifeValues[i] = ((Player)playerList[i]).Life;
        }
    }
}
```